# Add a new topic to a forum

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create the code that allows only users that are signed in to create a new topic in a forum.

I have a forum.php, topic_process.php, reply_process.php page. The forum is all set up and only displays the forms to post a new topic or new reply for users that are signed in, I set the forms in the forum.php as action="topic_process.php". However I am struggling with the topic_process.php page, here is the code I have and when I try to post a topic it simply echoes out 'you are not able to post a new topic'.

Here is the overview of the forumtopic table:

```
forumtopic_id, 
forumtopic_forumcategory_id,
forumtopic_title, 
forumtopic_text,
forumtopic_user_id, 
forumtopic_date,
```

And here is the code that I have in the topic_process.php page. (Please bare in mind that I haven't put in any validation stuff, etc but will do after I can get it to post into the database) Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

include "includes/pagetop.php";


 $query  = "newtopic;";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result)
{

    echo 'You are not able to post a new topic, please try again later';
}
else
{


    $sql = "INSERT INTO forumreply
    (
                       formtopic_forumcategory_id,
                       forumtopic_title,
                       forumtopic_text,
                       forumtopic_user_id,
                       forumtopic_date
                       )
           VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . "',
                       NOW(),
                       " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                       " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
                       )";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);



    {
        //the first query worked, now start the second, posts query
        //retrieve the id of the freshly created topic for usage in the posts query
        $topicid = mysql_insert_id();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO forumtopic
                    (
                       formtopic_forumcategory_id,
                       forumtopic_title,
                       forumtopic_text,
                       forumtopic_user_id,
                       forumtopic_date
                          )
                VALUES
                    ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']) . "',
                          NOW(),
                          " . $topicid . ",
                          " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
                    )";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'An error occured while inserting your post. Please try again later.' . mysql_error();
            $sql = "ROLLBACK;";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "COMMIT;";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            //after a lot of work, the query succeeded!
            echo 'You have successfully created <a href="topic.php?id='. $topicid . '">your new topic</a>.';
        }
    }
}




 ?>



     ?>
```

Comment: which is part of the database connection?

Comment: Where are you connecting to the database? `pagetop.php`?

Comment: in pagetop.php I have the connection script to the db

Comment: just for testing, try to connect to the database and have a $handler variable to use it while executing queries, and use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query, and let me know :)

Comment: @user3617344 `$query  = "newtopic;";` this is your query?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your $result variable

your problem is here

```
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result)
```

try to add

```
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   var_dump($result);
   exit();
   if(!$result)
```

and check your result from query

because your problem is what query returning

Comment: it showing a syntax error after that within the echo

Comment: Use var_dump($result) not echo $result, and show me your code let me check it.

Comment: this is the result I get, when trying to post a new topic, 'bool(false)'

Comment: $query  = "newtopic;"; this is not mysql statement, so mysql_query($query) return false in failure, and its fail cause the mysql statement is wrong.

Comment: so the statement needs to be changed?

Comment: Sure dude, look down you wrote a good sql statement ( INSERT INTO forumreply .... ), so what do you want to do first is check if user logged in using mysql ?

Comment: I don't need to check to see if they are logged in, because it checks if the user is logged in within the forum.php page. It will not display the 'post new topic' form unless they are logged in.

Comment: Ah ok,  so what is the result you expect from $query  = "newtopic;";
$result = mysql_query($query);